# Добавлять новые сообщения в чате в title

Tags: javascript, чат

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите, пожалуйста, решить такую задачу. Есть чат, и я хочу сделать такую вещь, когда человек сидит на других вкладках (т.е. не в чате), в <title> писалось, сколько новых сообщений, и этот счетчик обновлялся каждые 2 секунды. Я смог сделать только так:

```
function updateTitle(){
        window.onblur = function(){
            if(notread != 0)
                $('title').text(notread + ' новых сообщений');
            else
                $('title').text('ЧАТ СНУЯЭиП');
        }

        window.onfocus = function(){
            notread = 0;
        }
    }
```

Но проблема в том, что данные обновляются, только когда я ухожу с вкладки, а сама по себе она не обновляется. Скажите, как можно обновлять её постоянно, без обязательного нахождения человека на этой вкладке? Аналог можно увидеть в диалогах Вконтакте.

Comment: setTimeout/setInterval ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var refresh_interval = setinterval(function(){ 
        if(notread != 0)
            $('title').text(notread + ' новых сообщений');
        else
            $('title').text('ЧАТ СНУЯЭиП');},1000);//1000мс = 1секунда

//Чтобы остановить обновление
clearinterval(refresh_interval);
```